# Remove data-attribute with Jquery on lower resolutions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide the following data attribute `data-snap-ignore="true"` only for resolutions lower than 880px, but I can't find how to do it.

The reason to do that, is because snap.js uses the following data to disable the drag event on the content, so I am interested on hide it on lower resolutions (mobiles and tablets users are used to work with drag event).

HTML WITH DATA:

```
<div id="content" class="snap-content" data-snap-ignore="true">
 Content of the website
 </div>
```

**EDIT:**

The function code:

```
            var target = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement,
                ignoreParent = utils.parentUntil(target, 'data-snap-ignore');

            if (ignoreParent) {
                utils.dispatchEvent('ignore');
                return;
            }
```

As you can see it works with the `data-snap-ignore` only, without taking care on `true` or `false`, so it should be replaced maybe for some kind of white content, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use:

```
if($(window).width() < 880) {
    $('#content').attr('data-snap-ignore','false');
} else {
    $('#content').attr('data-snap-ignore','true');
}
```